# Magento 2 - which folder the installed extension will be

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have to install the extension in server.
So I tried **Web setup Wizard**, but I'm facing component dependency readiness issues 
So I checked and got a solution like to run the update query in the shell, but I don't have SSH access to run, just I have FTP and backend admin rights only

I planned to install the extension in local and move to server. Is any problem ll occur in this ?
If I tried this way then, where can I see the installed file?

I'm trying the below extension https://marketplace.magento.com/vsourz-imagegallery.html

Or is any other way to install?

Below Check my error while installing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The extensions is in the folder `your-website-root-folder/app/code/`.

From the screenshot, your problem is **conflicting component dependencies**, so maybe you need disable some conflicting extensions before install the extension you want.

Comment: how to find the conflicting extension?

Comment: Did you install some other extensions about image or banner? Try to disable them. If you have more detailed error message, show it in the question will have a help too.